# Java: interrupt accept method without close the server socket

Tags: java, serversocket

Is there any way to interrupt a `while(true)` accepting clients on a server socket, without calling `close` the server socket and throwing an exception?

Is there, for example, a timeout that the `accept` method can have?

Comment: What's the use case for wanting to interrupt the loop but *not* wanting to close the socket? If you want to keep the socket open, why not continue running the loop?

Comment: Just looking for a smoother way of interrupt the cycle withou forcing the close.

Comment: You're just restating the question and not providing any background. I wonder *why* you need to interrupt the cycle if you intend to keep the socket open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set server socket timeout with [setSoTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout(int)).
Once expired a SocketTimeoutException is raised.